# Is it possible to create a macOS .bunde library/plugins in Qt using qmake?

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I tried the lib_bundle flag but it is generating a .framework bundle. I also tried the -bundle -dynamiclib options and those flag are giving me a single file not a bundled library. I can create the bundle with BNDL Bundle type code manually by editing its info.plist and creating its own package/bundle, which is not the right way or not the fastest way. The thing that i want to know is... can it be created or generated using qmake? If not, is there any way to bundled my Qt Plugins programatically?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use Xcode and select the "Bundle" template for a new project? Seems like the path of least resistance. If you did that, you could use the `xcodebuild` command to build it from the command line.

Comment: It is because the plugin is Qt based. If i am going to use the xcode, how can i add my plugins/dylib in the bundle template project?

Comment: Isn't Qt written in C++? You can add C++ files to your bundle project in Xcode.

Comment: Yes some of them, but we are also using Qt libraries/frameworks and i think Xcode will not reconized it.